# SPARQL Query for Searching in Ontology using Jena API

Tags: java, sparql, jena, owl, ontology

Hi i am working on **Final Year Project** which is a basically **Jobs Search Engine using Ontology**. The technology i am using is Java.

The way it works is that the user searches any job, For example: Java developer and then that keyword should go in the Ontology created and get matched in Ontology . Once its matched then it will go the Xml file which contains all the jobs and get only the jobs which are have matched.

The Ontology has been successfully created and the only problem is that i am having trouble understanding and writing **SPARQL query with Jena API** that will be take the user typed keyword and go into the **OWL or RDF Ontology file** and find match then from there go to the xml data file and get only the matching data and display it on page.

This is the code i have written. i am only able to read ontology and i decided first to display them properly but i am getting error.

```
    OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel( OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM_MICRO_RULE_INF);
    String inputFileName="e:/springmvc/jena/bin/jena/ontology14.owl";
    InputStream in = FileManager.get().open( inputFileName );
    if (in == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
             "File: " + inputFileName + " not found");
    }
    model.read(in, null);

    String queryString =
            "prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> "+       
            "prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> "+       
            "select ?ab where {?person owl:equivalentClass ?ab " +
            "}";
    Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);
    QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model);
    ResultSet results =  qe.execSelect();
    while(results.hasNext()){
        QuerySolution soln = results.nextSolution();
        Literal jobs = soln.getLiteral("x");
        System.out.println(jobs);
    }
    qe.close();
```

Error i am getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.ResourceImpl cannot be cast to com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Literal
at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.core.QuerySolutionBase.getLiteral(QuerySolutionBase.java:41)
at jena.jeena.main(jeena.java:79)
```

Comment: the keyword is a string, we don't know what your jobs are in the ontology. Just URIs, or also for example an `rdfs:label` attached to the job? anyways, SPARQL has FILTER functions like `regex` or `contains`

Comment: brother can you be a little more specific on how to write this! and yes it is rdf:labels

Comment: I'm clearly not your "brother" ... and it's called `rdfs:label`. And not even showing a SPARQL query you tried is weird. I'm not doing your project, SPARQL tutorials are online. Hint: `select ... where { ... filter(contains(str(?label), "SEARCH_STRING_HERE"))}` - note, this will not do any fuzzy search but just do string containment check. Anything beyond need a fulltext search index like Lucene or ES

Comment: @AKSW  i have updated the question with code. kindly check!

Comment: @JamesZ  check the updated question

Comment: copy and paste code from somewhere is useless. It's obvious that your code doesn't work. 1) Look at your query 2) look at the value of which variable you're trying to get in the code 3) think about the difference between URIs and literals in RDF 4) don't copy and past code from different sources without understanding even the basics of RDF and SPARQL

Comment: 5) using `owl:equivalentClass` for persons is somehow weird ...